# SAS code to transpose and rename variables in a specific column before importing

Tags: sas, rename, transpose, sas-macro

I am using the macro provided below to import several csv files which works great. I am however struggling to transpose columns 3 and 6 in my dataset from columns to rows before importing. I would then like to rename these columns as date and study respectively.

(Right now for example each file has a different date in column 3 as the column name which I would like to bring down to the row and give the column a new name i.e. date such that when I set all the imported files one below the other all will be in the column called `date`)

I would not know in advance what column 3 would be named in each of my files. So for example in file 1 it can be named `XYZ`and `YYX` in file 2 and I want to name both `date` and also bring both `XYZ` and `YYX` to row instead. Examples are below:

In File 1:

```
| Pt | Rt | XYZ |
|----|----|------|
| 1  | 2  |       |
```

In File 2:

```
| Pt | Rt | YYZ |
|----|----|------|
| 3  | 4  |       |
```

The result should look like:

```
| Pt | Rt | date |
|----|----|-------|
| 1  | 2  | XYZ |
| 3  | 4  | YYX |
```

Code:

```
%*Creates a list of all files in the DIR directory with the specified extension (EXT);

%macro list_files(dir,ext);

      %local filrf rc did memcnt name i;

      %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf,&dir));

      %let did=%sysfunc(dopen(&filrf));



      %if &did eq 0 %then

            %do;

                  %put Directory &dir cannot be open or does not exist;



                  %return;

            %end;



      %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(dnum(&did));

            %let name=%qsysfunc(dread(&did,&i));



            %if %qupcase(%qscan(&name,-1,.)) = %upcase(&ext) %then

                  %do;

                        %put &dir\&name;

                        %let file_name =  %qscan(&name,1,.);

                        %put &file_name;



                        data _tmp;

                              length dir $512 name $100;

                              dir=symget("dir");

                              name=symget("name");

                              path = catx('\',dir,name);

                              the_name = substr(name,1,find(name,'.')-1);

                        run;



                        proc append base=list data=_tmp force;

                        run;



                        quit;



                        proc sql;

                              drop table _tmp;

                        quit;



                  %end;

            %else %if %qscan(&name,2,.) = %then

                  %do;

                        %list_files(&dir\&name,&ext)

                  %end;

      %end;



      %let rc=%sysfunc(dclose(&did));

      %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf));

%mend list_files;



%*Macro to import a single file, using the path, filename and an output dataset name must be specified;

%macro import_file(path, file_name, dataset_name );



      proc import

            datafile="&path.\&file_name."

            dbms=csv

            out=&dataset_name replace;

      run;



%mend;



*Create the list of files, in this case all CSV files;

%list_files(C:\Users\baidw002\Documents\1 BCH-LJAF\Real data transfer (BCH to UAB)\CGM\cgmtestfiles\machine\csv, csv);



%*Call macro once for each entry in the list table created from the %list_files() macro;

data _null_;

      set list;

      string = catt('%import_file(', dir, ', ',  name,', ', catt('test', put(_n_, z2.)), ');');

      call execute (string);

run;
```

Code originally from: https://github.com/statgeek/SAS-Tutorials/blob/master/Import_all_files_one_type

**Edit1:** As suggested in the first comment.

**Edit2:** added link to the source of the code.

Comment: Your program is using PROC IMPORT to read the file.  So unless you want to change that your real question could just start with an example of one of the resulting SAS datasets and explain what you need to change in it.  It kind of sounds like you just want to rename the third column, but you don't know in advance what name it currently has.  So show an example dataset and how you want it changed.

Comment: @Tom Thank you for your comment. I updated my question according to your comment.

Comment: Do all of the files have the same structure?  If so why are you using PROC IMPORT instead of a data step to read them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do the whole thing with one data step?  SAS can read CSV files directly without using PROC IMPORT.

Use a wildcard in the filename to read all of the files at once.
When you are on the first line of a file then read the DATE from the header row.

```
%let path=C:\Users\baidw002\Documents\1 BCH-LJAF\Real data transfer (BCH to UAB)\CGM\cgmtestfiles\machine\csv;
data want ;
  length pt 8 rt 8 date 8 ;
  informat date anydtdte.;
  format date yymmdd10.;

  length dummy $1 fname $256;
  infile "&path/*.csv" filename=fname truncover dsd ;
  input @;
  if fname ne lag(fname) then do;
    input 2*dummy date ;
    retain date;
  end;
  input pt rt ;
  drop dummy;
run;
```

So if I make up some dummy files:

```
%let path=%sysfunc(pathname(work));
data _null_;
  file "&path/test1.csv";
  put 'pt,rt,3/4/19' / '1,2';
  file "&path/test2.csv";
  put 'pt,rt,4/5/19' / '3,4';
run;
```

I get this result:

```
Obs    pt    rt          date

 1      1     2    2019-03-04
 2      3     4    2019-04-05
```

Comment: How will SAS identify the column "date" in each of the files since they all have different names i.e. XYZ and YYX? It gives error: https://i.imgur.com/c6I0v0C.jpg

Comment: That code is reading the third value of header row as the `date` variable. It also assumes it looks like a date value and stores it as a SAS date value.  You could modify the type (length) and informat and format to read it as something else.  Your picture doesn't show enough of the log to diagnosis the error.  Could be as simple as you pasted in some invisible characters into your editor window.

Comment: The variable is not formatted as a date variable should be so it is not in the format mmddyy.

Comment: Just read it as character then.  Why did you call it date if it isn't a date?

Comment: The date is written as _3_4_19

Comment: Does it literally have the leading underscore? Or did PROC IMPORT add those to make it a valid variable name?

Comment: Not sure. Sorry for the confusion. I will check now.

Comment: If the values in the header rows literally have an extra leading underscore you could try just adding a `+1` cursor movement command to the input statement to skip over the underscore.  `input 2*dummy +1 date ;`

Comment: I received error: https://i.imgur.com/a7p6jnO.jpg Also I have several `csv` files in the folder.

Comment: This error is when I use the first statement in the code.